# How to plot a path from GPS locations using Nokia Here maps?

Tags: javascript, node.js, gps

I am working on a GPS tracking system and I want to plot the locations of the device in the form of a route.

The problem that exists is there is a REST API for that but my client-side app uses socket.io to receive the locations from the server. How can I achieve that? Is there any way it can be changed in real time?

My software's design is something like this 
[image]

Till now I was plotting positions in the form of markers[image]

2) Should I plot paths between every consecutive pair or there is any other workaround?

socket update rate  ~ 5s
level of route display precision (accuracy to 2m)

Comment: Several issues to consider... rate limits in here api, socket update rate, level of route display precision needed

Comment: socket update rate  ~ 5s
level of route display precision (accuracy to 2m)

Comment: So what sort of interval can the api plan handle? I assume it's not free after certain number of requests (I haven't used it for a long time)

Comment: https://developer.here.com/faqs
Check out the link, couldn't post a screenshot!
The fourth point!
Does that mean I can't cater to more than 3 users in 5 minutes? How will I scale the application?

Comment: Issues like that are off-topic here. Nobody here can help you assess your business model or account needs. There are also other services for directions

Comment: Yes, that wasn't my original question though, it just occurred to me after seeing that!
So keeping in mind, the latency and the interval
" Should I plot paths between every consecutive pair or there is any other workaround?"

Comment: Why would the precision be low? I have the packets from GPS device and can use it once in every 5 minutes to plot the path using the array. Precision depends on the device and not on the API, what I want from the API is just to join the traces!

Comment: disregard... I wasn't thinking meters...was thing `m` for miles. How you do it sounds more like a business decision first. Note that reverse geocoding services might also be helpful depending on what overall requirements are

Comment: I'm not making it for a lot of users, it's just that right now I'm testing it for 3 devices. The pricing and all the other factors are of no concern right now!
Not focussing on the business aspect!

Comment: you can also draw your own lines between points....and get specific details on demand

Comment: Yes, that's what I want to know about! I wasn't able to find that! Have you ever tried that? Were there any caveats in that?

Comment: All map apis have line drawing overlay capabilites

Comment: What I found was only polygon shapes overlay and not a path, sometimes when the GPS misses a heartbeat, the location might lie in two different streets and that deviate it from it's original path!

Comment: Correct.... doesn't mean you can match streets in your own overlay, need a routes api to do that

Comment: The problem comes back to square one!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161996/discussion-between-abhishek-yadav-and-charlietfl).

Answer (score 0):

There is a route matching API available. This computes the most probable route from a GPS trace in a POST request body, using a standard format such as GPX, NMEA, KML or CSV.

The documentation can be found here: developer.here.com/documentation/route-match

For illustration purposes, below is a GET request. For production please use POST.

```
https://m.fleet.ls.hereapi.com/2/calculateroute.json
?apiKey={YOUR_API_KEY}
&routeMatch=1
&mode=fastest;car;traffic:disabled
&waypoint0=51.10177,0.39349
&waypoint1=51.10181,0.39335
&waypoint2=51.10255,0.39366
&waypoint3=51.10398,0.39466
&waypoint4=51.10501,0.39533
```

The response to the above request includes a JSON object with the following elements:

- GPS trace points matched on the route in the waypoint section
- the most probably driven route in the section leg with a sequence of links
- information about illegal, dangerous or unexpected behavior in the warnings section